# Cygwin CSV sort data by column

Tags: shell, csv, cygwin

### UPDATE 2:

OK I can't get this to work properly, it was working on one file but not another:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\sort -t"," -k5,2 c:\tmp\CI-tosplit.csv > c:\tmp\CI-DEN-sorted.csv
```

This seems to sort the data but it's ignoring the header, I thought the ,2 was saying start @ line 2 which it does on one file but not another.

All I am trying to do is sort a csv file by column 5 and keep the header.

Thanks again for all the input.

### UPDATED:

OK I've now switched to cygwin for this and I'm using the following command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin>sort -t"," -k8 c:\tmp\test.csv > c:\tmp\test-sorted.csv
```

-t to set deliminiter
-k for column number 12

This works, but I cannot get the header to stay in place.

Any input would be great, thanks guys.

---

I am trying to sort a CSV by a specified column using awk, but I cannot find anything that works.

```
sort -t, -k2 - u test.csv
```

Input file specified two times.

Please help, I am using Windows BTW.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is `- u` ??

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only output is input specified two times. I think it's an issue on windows as windows has a sort command. I'm struggling to find a fix though.

Comment: are you using cygwin sort or the windows sort command ? http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-07/msg01696.html has a similar problem with cygwin path

Comment: Just updated question using cygwin sort now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah got it: sort -t"," -k5,2 c:\tmp\test.csv > c:\tmp\test-sorted.csv

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using sort rather than awk.  which has a -u option (no space) for unique, also the -t option should have a value (the seperator).  Try:

```
sort -t, -k2 -u test.csv
```

Comment: Again I get Input file specified two times. so I'm pretty sure it's the sort command having issues...

Comment: I can't find much on using awk's sort perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, is there a way to specify a column to sort with awk?

Comment: did you remove the space between - and u ?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else does find this useful, I found the easiest way to sort csv files by columns was using cygwin, the following works for me:

```
sort -t"," -k5,2 c:\tmp\test.csv > c:\tmp\test-sorted.csv
```

-t set the determiner
-K Columnn , 2 for line 2 if you have a header
input file
output file

Thanks for all the input guys.

Comment: Arrrgghh just tried it on another file and the header is sorting.... Anybody know how to skip the header?